# I have forgate 60c firewall i want to block fb andyoutube in my network in some specific Ip Range , please informe me full process?

Tags: fortigate

I have forgate 60c firewall i want to block fb and youtube in my network in some specific Ip Range , please informe me full process?

Comment: Hi, since this is all done in GUI, I would suggest you watch the **Fortinet Cookbook Video - Blocking Facebook**. Once you know how to do facebook, you can apply the same to youtube. Just google it and you should find a link or visit the fortinet site for more examples.

Comment: Please refer to the Fortigate Cookbook which will teach you best practice ways to do so.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

1 step: Create Address group by clicking on policy&Objects. Expand the objects and select address when select address you can create address group by giving name like blocked users.

2. Step: create address in same panel by selecting create new give username, select type from drop down IP range, Select subnet range/ IP range like 192.168.0.100-192.168.0.100 this an example. You give you user IP address as same way.

3 Step: add users to blocked users group.

4 step. Go to security profiles select web filtering on the right hand side top corner you will see add button with symbol + and select what types of website you need to allow.

5 step select application control select the categories social media to block.

6 step select add signature you will get popup in that popup there will be search box type facebook you get all facebook related signatures select all of them and click on use selected signatures. Has same type youtube and do the same process as facebook.

7 step: go to policy and objects create policy for incoming outgoing.